# Verb preceding 'aber' in second clause

Tags: word-order, conjunction

From [Wikitionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitkommen):

> Ich würde gerne mit euch mitkommen, bin aber leider krank.

The position of 'bin' confuses me. Is it placed before 'aber' for stylistic reasons? Does it change the meaning of the sentence in any way?

And more importantly, is this indicative of a more general type of clause (i.e. where finite verbs can precede the clause's conjunction)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjunctions cannot follow the verb in German. It actually one of the defining features that they don't. 
The "aber" in your example is no conjunction. It is an adverb.

*"Bei aber im Mittelfeld handelt es sich um ein Konjunktionaladverb..."*

(Source:  "Duden, Die Grammatik" 8. Auflage, Seite 623)

It has the same position as other adverbs that express roughly the same:

> ..., gehe [aber/jedoch/trotzdem/dennoch] zur Arbeit.

or as adverbs in general.

> ..., gehe [dann, deshalb, dorthin, so] zur Arbeit

The sentence is as constructed as follows:

> ..., ich (subject, omitted for stylistic reasons) - bin (verb) - aber (adverb) - ....

So the only special thing here is the ellipsis.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Hier ist euer Streit ja noch schlimmer als bei der anderen Antwort. Also nochmal: Tohuwahohu geht von der Feldertheorie aus, Emanuel von der Wortartentheorie (oder wie die heißt). Jetzt macht den anderen nicht zur Schnecke, weil seine Theorie die relevanten Aspekte der anderen Theorie missachtet oder ignoriert. Genau darum geht es bei Modellen.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich habe leider doch etwas mehr Zeit gebraucht, um die Dinge mit hinreichendem Abstand zu sehen - es tut mir leid, ich hatte auf Deinen ersten Kommentar hin völlig überreagiert und bitte Dich um Entschuldigung. Selbst wenn die Wortart für meinen Lösungsansatz nicht relevant sein sollte, ist terminologische Klarheit doch wichtig - daher ist es in der Tat sinnvoll, den Begriff der Konjunktion nur dann einzusetzen, wenn er zweifelsfrei passt. Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend angepasst und wegen der zahlreichen Detailsfragen in ein Community Wiki umgewandelt.

Comment: PS: Ich habe meine Kommentare entfernt, da die Sachfragen besser innerhalb der Antwort(en) behandelt werden und die unsachlichen Dinge besser weder in Antworten noch Kommentaren ihren Platz haben sollten.

Answer (score 2):

> [...], bin aber leider krank.
>
> [...], aber ich bin leider krank.

The purpose of the first form is probably to save a word (ich), since "[...]aber bin leider krank." sounds a bit strange or at least very colloquial.

But these two forms of course express exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice question! The example demonstrates the combination of two substantive clauses („Satzzusammenziehung“), in combination with an ellipsis of the personal pronoun „ich“. Moving the „aber“ into the „[Mittelfeld](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/index.html)“ of the sentence is not a matter of style. It is not a a special case **for the position of the finite verb**. Rather, it's a matter of **positioning the word „aber“**. If you put it directly before the finite verb, you put it **into the „[Vorfeld](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Vorfeld.html)“ of the sentence (as its *sole* component)**. But „aber“ can't be placed as sole component into the „Vorfeld“, it isn't „*vorfeldfähig*“ (sorry for using german technical terms, but i don't know the exact english equivalent) - see also [Grammis on such connecting words](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_id=1278).

To make it short: When dropping the „ich“ in the second sentence (...**, bin** aber leider...“), the „Vorfeld“ of the second sentence is empty. Moving the „aber“ into the „Vorfeld“ would make it **the only part of the „Vorfeld“**, but this isn't allowed. So - figuratively spoken - dropping the personal pronoun from the „Vorfeld“ forces the „aber“ to the „Mittelfeld“ of the sentence.

EDIT:

Regarding the second part of the question - to be precise, conjuctions never follow the finite verb. See [Emanuel's answer on this point](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15164/verb-preceding-aber-in-second-clause/15175#15175).